# When moving one container down both move

Tags: html, css

So I have a container called banner within a container called main as so:

```
<div id="main"> <!-- BEGIN MAIN -->
<div id="banner"> <!-- BEGIN BANNER -->
</div> <!-- END BANNER -->
</div> <!-- END MAIN -->
```

Main is a gradient and banner is the banner I want to have kind of in the middle of that gradient. Left and right auto works great. But when I try to put a margin of 10px on top of the banner, both the main and banner move down. How do I make it so only the banner moves down? Thanks a bunch!

```
#main {

width: 1200px;
height: 440px;
background-image: url(../website/images/background_bg.png);

}

#banner {

width: 966px;
height: 367px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-top: 10px;
background-image: url(../website/images/banner.png);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add 10px of padding-top in your #main and it will solve the problem.

so you'll have:
`#main { padding-top: 10px; ... }`

Comment: you're welcome! Note that the other answer (from Mr. Alien) will also solve the problem but you'll be working with relative and absolute positioning, that you can simply avoid with padding. Also, don't forget to point an answer as the right one! ;)

Comment: What you said worked but if I look now, the 10px that I padded on the top, is now also pasted on the bottom. So it looks good until the bottom part where a part of the top of my gradient is pasted on the bottom of it. It's a gradient from light to dark and 10px of the light part has been pasted under the dark side.

Comment: No, the problem is that padding counts (adds up to) your height, so when you add 10px to padding-top, you also have to subtract 10px from your height. I thought you knew it. So you'll have `#main { padding-top: 10px; height: 430px; }` It's just how CSS works. Padding and borders will always be part of your height/width. An object of 100x100px with 10px of padding in each side and 2px border on each side will end up measuring 124x124px. Did you understand?

Comment: Ah, I get it. I'm sorry I've just started learning CSS. Thanks a lot

Comment: No problem! Just keep that in mind and it will avoid a lot of problems in the future ;)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `margin-top` you should use that:

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

Like this the `#banner` will be allways in the mid of the other container without having to specify a `margin-top` and `margin-bottom`.